# I bring the official application I uploaded to the Server with Android, but I cannot show it

Tags: java, android-imageview, mediastore

In my own application that I am trying to develop, I can upload the image to the server side. And using PHP with `getdetail` method, I can access which member's display ID in a function in the form of a string. When I set the corresponding profile_image ID to the image display area, the image is not visible. However, when I upload a picture as a user, it appears and when I return to the previous activity after saving, the picture disappears. What could be the reason, what kind of code should we write or what method should I follow?

Below are my code that give an idea:

```
private void getImageDetail(){

        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_IMAGE_READ,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Log.i(TAG, response.toString());

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("read");

                            if (success.equals("1")){


                                for (int i =0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){

                                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                   String strPhoto = object.getString("photo").trim();


                                    Uri filePath = Uri.parse(strPhoto);
                                    try {

                                        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                                        profile_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    //  Toast.makeText(HesapAyarActivity.this, strPhoto.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                }

                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(HesapAyarActivity.this, "Error Reading Detail "+e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(HesapAyarActivity.this, "Error Reading Detail "+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String > params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("id", getId);
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
    
    
 
 
 private void chooseFile(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "photo"), 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri filePath = data.getData();
            try {

                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                profile_image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            UploadPicture(getId, getStringImage(bitmap));

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I took care of my own business. With the Picasso library.

```
if (success.equals("1")){
    for (int i =0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String strPhoto = object.getString("photo").trim();
        if (strPhoto != null) {
            Picasso.get().load(strPhoto).into(profile_image);
        } else {
        }
    }
}
```